# Are police officer's families 2-4 times more likely to experience domestic violence?

Tags: united-states, violence, police

I was wondering the accuracy of this claim:

> Two studies have found that at least 40% of police officer families
>   experience domestic violence, ... in contrast to 10% of families in
>   the general population... A third study of older and more experienced
>   officers found a rate of 24% ..., **indicating that domestic violence is
>   2-4 times more common among police families than American families in
>   general.**

[Source](http://womenandpolicing.com/violenceFS.asp#notes)

The studies cited seem to be from the early 90's.

The only information I could find were a couple of news articles discussing this same website's claim:

- [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2014/09/police-officers-who-hit-their-wives-or-girlfriends/380329/)
- [KUTV](https://kutv.com/news/local/40-of-police-officer-families-experience-domestic-violence-study-says)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprise to discover that people with very stressful jobs (like being a police officer) are more likely to snap than people with less stressful jobs. If true, this is proof that we need to offer more support overwork less the people on the police forces.

Comment: It would not be surprising that this is true (though finding credible references is apt to be difficult).  After all, suicide is the single greatest cause of death of active duty police officers in the US.

Comment: @T.Sar Or people with a tendency towards violence choose a profession in which they can live out that dream. How do you decide which of these extreme positions is now true?

Comment: @FooTheBar My position isn't extreme. The police _is_ overworked, _is poorly paid_, and _have one of the most stressful jobs_ possible. _[Financial stress](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4771826/)_, for example is correlated to domestic violence, as is emotional stress, substance abuse, among others. I'm not saying by any means that DV is _excusable_, but it is something that is way more complicated than "choosing a job that allows you to follow violent dreams".

Comment: @FooTheBar [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3384540/) also reinforces several factors that increase the chance of domestic violence, citing both stress and financial problems as correlated to DV, among other things.

Comment: @FooTheBar So, answering your question "how we decide wich position is now true?", I say - In the Skeptics manner, of course: with Citations!

Comment: Do you also have DV numbers for similar stressful jobs?

Comment: @FooTheBar I tried to find it but wasn't so lucky. I found and a couple of article with some remotely related issues (paramedics being more prone to suicide than the general population, for example). My guess is that police violence -> domestic violence is a easy link to think about, so it is more researched than other professions and domestic violence. My second link however explains that blue-collar and poorly paid jobs are more often linked to domestic violence than other jobs with a better financial situation. Further education also seems to reduce the chance for DV.

Comment: I found a nice Thesis https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/47a8/cd5d44c5714381f54f06d4f21b96d87c4a4d.pdf

Comment: Another factor to consider is whether domestic violence by police officers is more likely or less likely to go unreported. (I do not pretend to know if either is the case.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Officer-Involved Domestic Violence: The
Mediating Factors](https://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1066&context=themis) *Themis: Research Journal of Justice Studies and
Forensic Science*: Vol. 6 , Article 9 (2018):

> Various new studies have provided researchers with
>   more valid and credible data regarding the relationship between
>   factors of the workplace, and violence in police families. This
>   data is collected through an unbiased manner and is more
>   credible. Multiple small studies done regarding correctional
>   workers residing in the state of Florida utilize the McCreary and Thompson questionnaire created in 2006. This method provides
>   participants with specific questions, and their answers are graded
>   on a one (no stress) to seven (high stress) scale (Summerlin et
>   al., 2010). The studies found that **in the population of
>   correctional officers and police officers, domestic violence
>   occurs at rates 40% greater than the public** (2010). A study
>   conducted of 479 officers from other Eastern states found that
>   60% of the spouses were victims of verbal abuse. This
>   demonstrates that verbal abuse is an existing aspect of martial
>   disputes (Johnson, Todd, & Subramanian, 2005).
>
> Additional studies carried out examined the Baltimore
>   police department between 1997 and 1999. Using proctor administered
>   surveys as the main method, two outside studies
>   found that 40% of police families had experienced partner
>   violence (Johnson, 1991 as cited in Anderson & Lo, 2011). The
>   1,104 participants of this study were all sworn, full-time law
>   enforcement employees of the Baltimore P.D. Of the 1,104
>   officers, 9% of them admitted to losing control at home, and
>   potentially engaging in acts of domestic violence against their
>   respective intimate partners (Anderson & Lo, 2011). A
>   significant correlation is visible in police officer family violence
>   because they have more cases of domestic and/or family
>   violence than families of the public. Taken from family violence
>   statistics presented by the U.S Department of Justice, between
>   1998 and 2002, only 11% of reported violence was family
>   violence, a minute statistic when compared to that of police
>   families (BJS, 2005).
>
> The body of research done by Stinson and Liederbach
>   (2012) provides the greatest amount of empirical data on OIDV
>   to date. Their research reviews incidents in which police officers
>   were arrested for criminal offenses that were potential cases of 
>   domestic violence. The crimes were collected from newspaper
>   articles available to the public, and only crimes that met a
>   standard of reliability were considered (Stinson & Liederbach,
>   2012). A 97.7% degree of reliability was established upon
>   simple agreement between two coders across all variables of the
>   study, which is above the considered reliable percentage (Stinson
>   & Liederbach, 2012). The degree of reliability tells us that the
>   cases studied are perceived in a less biased manner, and provide
>   statistically consistent data. In total, 324 cases met the
>   requirements, and were part of the research. Of the 324 cases, 74
>   occurred in 2005, 116 occurred in 2006, and the remaining 138
>   occurred in 2007. The significance of the data comes from the
>   fact that 98.8% of the arrests were of off-duty officers. Out of the
>   312 OIDV victims: 104 were the current spouse of the officer, 71
>   were a child or stepchild of the officer, and the remaining were
>   other relatives (2012).

Where "Summerlin" is Summerlin, Z., Oehme, K., Stern N., & Valentine, C. (2010).
[Disparate levels of stress in police and correctional
officers: Preliminary evidence from a pilot study on
domestic violence](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1080/10911351003749169). *Journal of Human Behavior in the
Social Environment*, 20(6), 762-777.

Comment: "Martial disputes" should be "marital disputes", right?

Comment: @EikePierstorff probably, error is in the original text

Comment: There was this movie "Mr. and Mrs. Smith" where we had both :-)